# Display of documents on the basis of the Respective Office User

Tags: sharepoint

My requirement is like this.

I have one document library and now I have 600+ Offices with different users in their respective offices and now I need to display the documents such that the logged in user should be able to see only the documents of his office.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. You create a property in the User Profile of all users describing which offices are assigned to which user. You can then add a Filter WebPart next to your document library filtering the library according to this property of the current user.
2. You create Active Directory groups for each Office and assign the users to that group. You then filter the document libraries' view on the current user & his groups.